# invalid_request:redirect_uri mismatch in tizen studio

Tags: tizen-studio, samsung

while i am creating profile in certificate manager in tizen studio .
after fill the detail it's taking to Samsung account singing. It redirection Samsung page i am getting the redirection error.

below one is error

> The website didn't understand the request from your browser.
>
> Error 400: Bad request
> invalid_request:redirect_uri mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you've installed latest version

Package Manager > Extension SDK > Samsung Certificate Extension > Version 2.0.65

And, would you check the account in https://account.samsung.com/membership in case you still have this issue ?

Thank you!